# Job processing number in terminal - queue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-8

What is the number next to time in the terminal if it is for processing amount how can I rest it to start from 0 every time running the command `php artisan queue:work` it starts to continue from last number stop on it, also it possible to change it to string?

I try to this command to clear caches `php artisan optimize:clear` but nothing cahnge

[image]

Comment: Those look like job IDs, which is generated by wherever the jobs are being stored. I would not recommend trying to change them

Comment: OK, but how if want to start from 0 and what will happen if reach to 99999999999 at that time the queue system will stop right?

Comment: Its the job number.  You can use this number to purge or retry a specific job.  In normal use it should be of no consequence to you and you can ignore it.
In recent versions the primary key on mysql can be 18446744073709551615 which you will not reach in your lifetime (other queue methods might have different limits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @aynber say it is job IDs, it is `autoincrement` in the job table, So I rest it by truncating the table after make sure no data in the table